# How can I combine ucwords and str_replace if I'm replacing several words/characters?

Tags: php, str-replace, capitalize

This works to combine ucwords and str_replace if I only need to replace one character:

```
echo str_replace('_', ' ', ucwords($cname));
```

This works to replace words/characters:

```
$search_name = array('_', ',', 'neckline', 'skirts', 'skirt','pants', 'neckline_size', 'sleeves', 'pants_length');
$replace_name = array(' ', ', ', '');
$rows = str_replace($search_name, $replace_name, $row);
echo $rows['silhouettes_like'];
```

But if I try combining them by adding this, it echo's "Array" instead of the value

```
$style_names = ucwords($rows);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function to map ucwords to each row value

```
$rows = array_map('ucwords', $rows);
```